# Add Text To TinyMCE Visual Pane In WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have successfully written a TinyMCE plugin for a WordPress site that inserts a script tag into the html of a new post or page. However, since the script tag contains no text, in the "visual" pane nothing shows up.

There must be a way to provide something to show in the visual pane while still only having a script tag in the "text" pane no?

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor, url) {

        editor.addButton('civicsciencejspoll', {
            text: 'CivicScience JSPoll',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                    var html = "<script src=\"mydomain.com/js/file.js\"></script>";
                    editor.insertContent(html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using WordPress's ShortCode API to achieve my desired effect:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: How did you acheive it? I just need a handler/icon in the visual editor that the user can center align so that the script tag (embed code) will be center aligned on the page.